# Google Chrome strange style behavior with negative margin on hover

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have this HTML code:

```
<nav id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Item1</a>
            <a href="#" class="alt">Item1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Item2</a>
            <a href="#" class="alt">Item2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

[Demo page](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9123555/menu-transition-chrome-test/index-simple.html)

As you can notice, it's a menu with 2 links for each item. The menu is horizontal, and the aim is to hide the "alt" link when the item is not hovered and to show it when it is hovered.

Each `<li>` element is therefore a box with a specific height (34px) and each link has a height of 34px as well, so that the "alt" link is below the main link, and is hidden.

When the item is hovered, a negative top margin of 34px is applied to the main link, making the "alt" one appear.

But when "hovering out" the top margin of 0 is not really applied back by Google Chrome as you can notice on the [demo page](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9123555/menu-transition-chrome-test/index-simple.html) I made. Just hover several times on the links and you will notice that elements are not put back to their correct positions.

How can I solve that? I need to keep 2 links (main and "alt") for more complex reasons, the demo being simplified.

For your information, here is the CSS:

```
nav#menu {
    background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

nav#menu > ul {
    margin: 0;
    height: 39px;
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav#menu > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 34px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
}

nav#menu > ul > li > a {
    display: block;
    height: 34px;
    line-height: 34px;
}

nav#menu > ul > li > a:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}

nav#menu > ul > li:hover > a:first-child {
    margin-top: -34px;
}

nav#menu > ul > li > a.alt {
    color: white;
    background-color: #8d8d8d;
}
```

Comment: I notice that it will work if you go slow between the two 'li' tags. It works fine if you just hover over the one element and off the one element, but when you go fast between the two 'lis' that is what it's having the issue. Weird.

Comment: Have you thought about using jQuery as an alternative?

Comment: I thought about using jQuery (especially as my menu is much more complex than the example I gave, with CSS3 transitions, submenus, etc.), but that's always frustrating when that can be done using CSS.
Anyway, you gave me the solution in your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for all the comments. I was trying to get it to work and just thinking out loud. Here is the solution you are looking for...

You need to change two of the styles.

```
/* add the overflow: hidden; to the end of this tag set */
nav#menu > ul {  .... overflow: hidden;  }  

/* replace the inline-block with float:left;*/
nav#menu > ul > li { float:left; height: 34px; overflow: hidden; width: 200px; }
```

Here is the working link [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5wbZU/1/)

Comment: Thank you, it works now, even with my non-simplified menu.
The `overflow: hidden` was useless on the `ul` (and I had to remove it so that my sub-menus work), but changing the inline-block (on which I rely too much on) to a float works fine!

Comment: the overflow:hidden was to get the simplified version to work. I am glad that you were able to use the other hint to get your menu working.

Comment: No problem, as it helped me to solve the problem. A look at the (almost) final version: http://jsfiddle.net/tcpK3/